# Equivalence of Tensor.storage() for Numpy Array and Tensorflow.Tensor?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I know in Pytorch we can check the underlying Tensor data storage by `torch.Tensor.storage()`. I think this is a practical method as sometimes the performance of Tensor depends on the underlying storage and with this method we can check it easily. I'm wondering if it also exists for Tensorflow Tensor or Numpy Array?

```
In [5]: t=torch.Tensor([[2,3,4],[5,6,7]])  
In [7]: t.storage()                                                                                                                    
Out[7]: 
 2.0
 3.0
 4.0
 5.0
 6.0
 7.0
[torch.FloatStorage of size 6]
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.storage